# Nifi for database migration

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata, apache-nifi

Why would nifi be a good use case for database migration if all it does is sending the same data over and over again?(I have tried to extract data from a database and putting them into a JSON file I was seeing multiple entries of the same tuple.) Wouldn't that be a waste of computing resources?

If I just want to migrate the database once and sometimes update the changed columns only, is nifi still a good tool to use?

Comment: What prompted you to look at nifi in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on which database you want to migrate from/to which environments. Is it a large enterprise Oracle DB you want to migrate into Hadoop? Look into Sqoop https://sqoop.apache.org/. I would recommend Sqoop for doing one-time imports of large databases into Hadoop.

You can use NiFi to do an import as well, using processors such as ExecuteSQL, QueryDatabaseTable, GenerateTableFetch... They all work with JDBC connectors, so depending on if your database supports this, you could opt for this as well.

If you want to get incremental changes, you could use the QueryDatabaseTable processor and use it's Maximum-Value Column property, Matt Burgess has an article explaining how you can put this in place over at https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/51902/incremental-fetch-in-nifi-with-querydatabasetable.html.